# how can I find repeated elements in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have a vector of `int` which can include maximum 4 elements and minimum 2, for example :

```
std::vector<int> vectorDATA(X); // x means unknown here
```

What I want to do is to erase the elements that are repeated  for example :

```
vectorDATA{1,2,2}     to vectorDATA{1,2}
vectorDATA{1,2,3}     to nothing changes
vectorDATA{2,2,2}     to vectorDATA{2}
vectorDATA{3,2,1,3}   to vectorDATA{3,2,1}
vectorDATA{1,2,1,2}   to vector{1,2}
```

and so on

here a code simple :

```
cv::HoughLines(canny,lineQ,1,CV_PI/180,200);
        std::cout << " line Size "<<lineQ.size()<< std::endl;
        std::vector<int> linesData(lineQ.size());
        std::vector<int> ::iterator  it;
        if(lineQ.size() <=4 && lineQ.size() !=0 ){
            if(lineQ.size()==1){
                break;
            }else {
            for ( int i = 0; i<lineQ.size();i++){
                linesData[i] = lineQ[i][1]; // my comparison parameter is the lineQ[i][1]
            }
```

// based on the answer I got I'm trying this but I really don't how to continue ?

```
std::sort(lineQ.begin(),lineQ.end(),[](const cv::Vec2f &a,const cv::Vec2f &b)
            {
                return ????
            }
```

I tried use a `for and do while` loop, but I didn't get it, and the function `std::adjacent_find` this has a condition that the elements should be consecutive.
Maybe it's easy but I just don't get it ! 
thanks for any help !

Comment: maximum 4, minimum 4. That's not really a wide choice of sizes :)

Comment: @jrok sorry about that  !

Comment: @Dukeling there you got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is sort then unique-erase, but this changes order.

The c++11 order preserving way is to create an `unordered_set<int> s;` and do:

```
unordered_set<int> s;
vec.erase(
  std::remove_if( vec.begin(),vec.end(), // remove from vector
    [&](int x)->bool{
      return !std::get<1>(s.insert(x)); // true iff the item was already in the set
    }
  ),
  vec.end() // erase from the end of kept elements to the end of the `vec`
);
```

which is the remove-erase idiom using the `unordered_set` to detect duplicates.

Comment: You can shorten this by simply inserting and checking the return value, as the insert will tell you whether the element already existed or not.

Comment: @Svalorzen shorter version used.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see a sort-less source code in the already mentioned answers, so here it goes. Hash table for checking duplicates, shifting unique elements towards the front of the vector, note that `src` is always `>= dst` and `dst` is the number of copied, i.e. unique elements at the end.

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void
uniq (std::vector<int> &a) {
    std::unordered_set<int> s;
    size_t dst = 0;
    for (size_t src = 0; src < a.size(); ++src) {
        if (s.count (a[src]) == 0) {
            s.insert (a[src]);
            a[dst++] = a[src];
        }
    }
    a.resize (dst);
}

int
main () {
    std::vector<int> a = { 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,2, 3, 1, 1 };
    uniq (a);
    for (auto v : a)
        std::cout<< v << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to realy remove repeated elements, you may try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>       

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int data[] = {1,2,3,2,1};
    vector<int> vectorDATA = (&data[0], &data[0] + 5);
    sort(vectorDATA.begin(),vectorDATA.end());

    for(int i = 0; i < vectorDATA.size()-1; ++i)
    {
        if(vectorDATA[i] == vectorDATA[i+1])
            vectorDATA.erase(vectorDATA.begin()+i+1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < vectorDATA.size();++i)
    {
        cout << vectorDATA[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Lack of of this method is then elements lost his order.

Comment: it'l work only if the repeated elements are consecutive !

Comment: @engine You forgot the sort that's being made before the remove.